# How to get from array with Timestamps - years, months, days in python?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

How can I get from array with Timestamps - years, months, days?
I have DataFrame where index is Timestamps and I try this

```
for i in data_frame.index:
    print(datetime.fromtimestamp(i).isoformat())
```

But I got this error:

```
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(i).isoformat()) ===>
===> TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first use `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestap'])` to convert to proper format
then create new columns for year, month, and day

```
df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df['month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df['day'] = df['date'].dt.day
```